# Permissions Plugin in Flutter

Tags: plugins, flutter, dart

I am trying to develop an android permissions plugin in Flutter but I am stack at ContextCompat error

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE} , 1);
      }

      if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG} , 1);
      }
```

Comment: What are you stuck with? How does this differ from your previous question?

Comment: on a previous question, I searched on other platforms too it did not seem like android X issue It likes I have lack of knowledge about how to call android component in flutter plugin